# Having an issue with <Leader> key and plugin (particularly EasyMotion)

Tags: vim, plugins

So I am really new to VIM but was attempting to add some plugin's one of which is EasyMotion.

According to the vid tutorials at NetPlus, and [Vim's Wiki Plugin Page](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526), after dropping the plugin's .vim file in the plugins direction (on Windows) I should be able to initiate the EasyMotion plugin by hitting (from within a loaded file):

`<Leader><Leader>`w"

And according to the VIM documentation, Leader is set to the mapleader variable which is by default "\" unless change.  I haven't changed it but hitting "\" does nothing but beep (windows error bell).

I did try even mapping:
let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","

and nothing changed.

**UPDATE**
I came across these errros when I accidently tried loading my _vimrc file by Vim (right clicked on file and chose to open with Vim) -> I think this might give some insight, but I haven't a clue why:

**ERROR**

Error detected while processing d:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\plugin\
EasyMotion.vim:

line   24:

E117: Unknown function: EasyMotion#InitOptions

line   39:

E121: Undefined variable: g:EasyMotion_hl_group_target

E116: Invalid arguments for function EasyMotion#InitHL

line   40:

E121: Undefined variable: g:EasyMotion_hl_group_shade

E116: Invalid arguments for function EasyMotion#InitHL

line   69:

E117: Unknown function: EasyMotion#InitMappings

Comment: Please try the command `:echo g:EasyMotion_loaded` to see if `EasyMotion` was even loaded.

Comment: @Idan - no responded "Undefined Variable".  It was my understanding that any .vim plugin in the /Vim/Vimfiles/plugins dir would get auto loaded?  I guess I am wrong?  In there documentation there isn't even reference that I would need to wire up loading through my _vimrc or some other way.

Comment: @pghtech - ":scriptnames" will tell you what Vim loaded and what not. Is your plugin in there?

Comment: yes, in the list is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\plugin\EasyMotion.vim

Comment: That means the file was sourced (i.e. "loaded"). That is good, means the problem is not with Vim's paths. Now you have to find out why it isn't "reacting". See my ... below, check out what is your <leader>. If  you wish define a new one with let mapleader = "," or something. See if you can "call EasyMotion" function?

Comment: I'm writing all of this from memory and from what I can find out off vim.org. Don't have Vim here (not my machine on which I'm now) :/

Comment: So I have updated my question with some additional info, and I have also tried mapping mapleader and g:mapleader and verified by :echo mapleader.  However, when I :echo $VIMFILES it doesn't return any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer came out to be that I had not added the autoload .vim file to the autoload directory.  This was why I was getting the specific errors.

Comment: Just to spell it out for future dummies like me: you have to copy `doc/easymotion.txt`, `plugin/EasyMotion.vim`, and `autoload/*` into the respective folders under `~/.vim/`. Like the OP I missed the latter, `autoload` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the aforementioned plugin, so cannot help with it specifically, but as far as the other part goes, you can see what your leader is mapped by

```
:echo g:mapleader
```

Vim plugins are usually (if you're not using some plugin to manage plugins, like Pathogen or Vim-Addon-Manager) saved either in $VIM\plugins (bad), or in $VIMFILES\plugins (good), on Windows. If you're on unix, just replace \ with /.

You can also find out where your $VIM, $VIMFILES ... directories are by echoing them ... `:echo $VIMFILES`.

One more thing about mapleader. It is not *dynamic* - that is, once the mapping is defined with

```
<leader>some_key
```

and you change the leader variable, it does not redefine the mapping. So your leader has to change (for example, in your vimrc) before the actual mapping that is using it *happens.*

Comment: So I have updated my question with some additional info, and I have also tried mapping mapleader and g:mapleader and verified by :echo mapleader. However, when I :echo $VIMFILES it doesn't return any response.